# Program to find largest and smallest among 5 numbers without using array

Tags: c++, c++11

Yesterday I went for an interview where I have been asked to create a program to find largest and smallest among 5 numbers without using array.

I know how to create the program using array.

```
int largestNumber;
int smallestNumber;
int numbers[n];

largestNumber=numbers[0];
smallestNumber=numbers[0];
for (i=0 ; i<n; i++)
{
if (numbers[i] > largestNumber) 
{
largest = numbers[i];
}
if (numbers[i] < smallestNumber) 
{
smallestNumber= numbers[i];
}
}
```

But how to create it without using array. Any help??

Comment: So where are the numbers, if they aren't in an array? In the cloud? :-)

Comment: std::cin, no storage at all, just max and min

Comment: Yes, you can do it without array.

Comment: With an array, `std::minmax_element` is a better solution than rolling your own.

Answer (score 19):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline const T&
max_of(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return std::max(a, b);
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
inline const T&
max_of(const T& a, const T& b, const Args& ...args) {
    return max_of(std::max(a, b), args...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << max_of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
    // Or just use the std library:
    std::cout << std::max({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So now apply that to a set of numbers read from `std::cin` without using an array (or similar storage).

Comment: That edit is important. I'm surprised no one has mentioned the initializer list form of `std::max` until now.

Comment: This won't work for arbitrarily sized inputs, like millions or billions of numbers.

Comment: @mvp: The question ask for 5... how do you come to bilions?

Comment: @mvp: `std::max_element`

Answer (score 10):

Works for any number of numbers taken from standard input:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<int> it_begin(std::cin), it_end;
    auto p = std::minmax_element(it_begin, it_end);
    if (p.first != it_end)
        std::cout << "min: " << *p.first << " max: " << *p.second;
}
```

Disclaimer:
Technicaly, this isn't required to work by C++ standard. The minimum iterator category required for `minmax_element` is `ForwardIterator` which stream iterators are not. Once an input iterator is dereferenced or incremented, its copies are no longer guaranteed to be dereferenceable or comparable to other iterators. It Works On My Machine<sup>TM</sup>. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
int min_num = INT_MAX;  //  2^31-1
int max_num = INT_MIN;  // -2^31
int input;
while (!std::cin.eof()) {
    std::cin >> input;
    min_num = min(input, min_num);
    max_num = max(input, max_num);
}
cout << "min: " << min_num; 
cout << "max: " << max_num;
```

This reads numbers from standard input until eof (it does not care how many you have - 5 or 1,000,000).

Comment: And what if I enter "hello" instead of a number?

Comment: This solution expects well formed input. Improving it to deal with bad input is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient answer but it still works

```
int a,b,c,d,e,largest;
if ((a>b) and (a>c) and (a>d) and (a>e))
{    
    largest=a;
}
else if ((b>a) and (b>c) and (b>d) and (b>e))
{    
    largest=b;
}
else if ((c>a) and (c>a) and (c>d) and (c>e))
{    
    largest=c;
}
else if ((d>a) and (d>c) and (d>a) and (d>e))
{    
    largest=d;
}
else 
{
largest=e;
}
```

you can use similar logic to fid the smallest value

Answer (score 0):

Let max will hold the maximum of 5 numbers. Assign the first number to max. Take the 2nd number and compare it with max if the the 2nd number is greater than max then assign it to max else do nothing. Next take the 3rd number and compare it with max , if the 3rd number is greater than max assign it to max else do nothing. Do the same for 4th and 5th number. Finally max will hold the maximum of 5 number.

Answer (score 0):

For example 5 consecutive numbers

```
int largestNumber;
int smallestNumber;
int number;
std::cin>>number;
largestNumber = number;
smallestNumber = number;
for (i=0 ; i<5; i++)
{
   std::cin>>number;
   if (number > largestNumber) 
   {
     largest = number;
   }
   if (numbers < smallestNumber) 
   {
     smallestNumber= number;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that the initialization of number consumes 1 of the 5 values, implying that your for loop is 1 too large.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` and `<` are transitive properties, so if `a > b` and `b > c`, then `a > c`. So you can

```
int a=10, b=6, c=4, d=21, e=4;

int maxNum = a;
int maxNum = max(b, maxNum);
int maxNum = max(c, maxNum);
int maxNum = max(d, maxNum);
int maxNum = max(e, maxNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list (or vector), which is not an array:

```
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list<int> l;
    l.push_back(3); 
    l.push_back(9); 
    l.push_back(30);    
    l.push_back(0); 
    l.push_back(5); 

    list<int>::iterator it_max = max_element(l.begin(), l.end());
    list<int>::iterator it_min = min_element(l.begin(), l.end());

    cout << "Max: " << *it_max << endl;
    cout << "Min: " << *it_min << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorting network!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    if (a < b) std::swap(a, b);
    if (d < e) std::swap(d, e);
    if (c < e) std::swap(c, e);
    if (c < d) std::swap(c, d);
    if (b < e) std::swap(b, e);
    if (a < d) std::swap(a, d);
    if (a < c) std::swap(a, c);
    if (b < d) std::swap(b, d);
    if (b < c) std::swap(b, c);

    std::cout << "largest = " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "smallest = " << e << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why sort when the task doesn't require sorting?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I was a little bored so my answer isn't completely serious.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep things simple, then here is my solution.

It works for any number of integers taken from standard input. It also works for negative integers. Enter end when you are done.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int max,min,input;
std::cout<<"Enter the number: ";
std::cin>>input;
min=max=input;

while(std::cin>>input){
    if(input>max) max=input;
    if(input<min) min=input;
    std::cout<<"Enter the number: ";
}
std::cout<<"\nMax: "<<max<<"\nMin: "<<min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
int a,b,c,d,e,max;
    max=a;
    if(b/max)
        max=b;
    if(c/max)
        max=c;
    if(d/max)
        max=d;
    if(e/max)
        max=e;
    cout<<"Maximum is"<<max;
}
```

Comment: Using a coding trick like this will probably work but to be an answer to teh question it needs some explanation about what it does and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I did, without using an array. This was a method to return the highest number of 5 scores.

```
double findHighest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
 {
   double highest = score1;
   if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3 && score2 > score4 && score2 > score5)
      highest = score2;
   if(score3 > score1 && score3 > score2 && score3 > score4 && score3 > score5)
      highest = score3;
   if(score4 > score1 && score4 > score2 && score4 > score3 && score4 > score5)
      highest = score4;
   if (score5 > score1 && score5 > score2 && score5 > score3 && score5 > score4)
      highest = score5;
   return highest;
 }
```

An array is going to be far more efficient, but I had to do it for homework without using an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMin(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4, int t5)
{
    int min1, min2, min3;

    min1 = std::min(t1, t2);
    min2 = std::min(t3, t4);
    min3 = std::min(min1, min2);
    return std::min(min3, t5);
}

int findMax(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4, int t5)
{
    int max1, max2, max3;

    max1 = std::max(t1, t2);
    max2 = std::max(t3, t4);
    max3 = std::max(max1, max2);
    return std::max(max3, t5);
}
```

These functions are very messy but easy to follow and thus easy to remember and it only uses the simple min and max methods which work best for 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMin(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4, int t5)
{
    int min;

    min = t1;
    if (t2 < min)
        min = t2;
    if (t3 < min)
        min = t3;
    if (t4 < min)
        min = t4;
    if (t5 < min)
        min = t5;

    return min;
}
```

```
int findMax(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4, int t5)
{
    int max;

    max = t1;
    if (t2 > max)
        max = t2;
    if (t3 > max)
        max = t3;
    if (t4 > max)
        max = t4;
    if (t5 > max)
        max = t5;

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation: Simple and short

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int max_of_five(int a, int b, int c, int d,int e){
    int large= max(max(a, b), max(c,d));
    return max(large,e);

}

int min_of_five(int a,int b,int c, int d,int e){
    int small=min(min(a,b),min(c,d));
    return min(small,e);
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d,e;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d,&e);
    int ans = max_of_five(a, b, c, d, e);
    int ans1=min_of_five(a,b,c,d,e);
    printf("Max:\t%d\n", ans);
    printf("Min:\t%d", ans1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int largestNumber;
    int smallestNumber;
    int temp1;
    cin >> temp1;
    largestNumber = temp1;
    smallestNumber = temp1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (temp > largestNumber)
            {
                largestNumber = temp;
            }
            if (temp < smallestNumber)
            {
                smallestNumber = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "smallest number is " << smallestNumber<<endl;
    cout << "lagest   number   is " << largestNumber<<endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you are running outer loop for 0-1-2-3-4, meaning 5 numbers, plus first entry makes it 6 numbers. fix the number. and inner loop runs the same operation 3 times, you need that operation only once. so remove the looping.