# Accept 5 numbers from user input and output the largest and smallest

Tags: c++

I'm extremely new to C++ and I was hoping you could help me with this code.

I have a feeling this should be extremely easy but I just can't wrap my head around how to do this and i've been searching the internet to no avail.

I just need to accept 5 numbers and then output the largest and smallest. I imagine I need to use a loop and then check through the numbers but I can't understand the logic needed behind this program. Any tips at all would be extremely beneficial.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
int numberCounter;
int number;
int number2;
int number3;
int number4;
int number5;
int largestNumber;
int smallestNumber;
numberCounter = 1;

while (numberCounter <= 5) {
    std::cout << "Please Enter a number";
    std::cin >> number >> number2 >> number3 >> number4 >> number5;
    numberCounter++;
}

if (number < number2) {
    number = smallestNumber;
    number2 = largestNumber;
}
else {
    number2 = largestNumber;
    number = smallestNumber;
}
if (number3 > largestNumber) {
    number3 = largestNumber;
}
else {
    if (number3 < smallestNumber) {
        number3 = smallestNumber;
    }
}
if (number4 > largestNumber) {
    number4 = largestNumber;
}
else {
    if (number4 < smallestNumber) {
        number4 = smallestNumber;
    }
}
if (number5 > largestNumber) {
    number5 = largestNumber;
}
else {
    if (number5 < smallestNumber) {
        number5 = smallestNumber;
    }
}

std::cout << "The smallest number is: " << smallestNumber << "\n";
std::cout << "The largest number is: " << largestNumber<< "\n";
}
```

I'm getting an error that says this: uninitialised local variable 'largestNumber' used.

Comment: Rather than `x = smallestNumber` you should be using `smallestNumber = x`. Same for `largestNumber`.

Comment: Why not simply initializing all of your variables to get rid of the error in 1st place?

Comment: Your `while`-loop is pointless since your `cin`-statement allready reads 5 integers, no matter what. No point of repeating anything there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I knew it would be a stupid reason as to why this isn't working. Sorry for the bad code, i'll be working on it.

Comment: you might get some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286384/program-to-find-largest-and-smallest-among-5-numbers-without-using-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working example

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numbers[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    std::cout << "Please Enter a number";
    for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
        std::cin >> numbers[z];
    }

    int largestNumber = numbers[0];
    int smallestNumber = numbers[0];

    for(int i = 1;i < 5; ++i)
    {
       if ( numbers[i] < smallestNumber )
             smallestNumber = numbers[i] ;

        if ( numbers[i] > largestNumber )
             largestNumber = numbers[i] ;

    }
    std::cout << "The smallest number is: " << smallestNumber << "\n";
    std::cout << "The largets number is: " << largestNumber << "\n";
}
```